# Objetos con atributos de vectores - relacion - Java

Tags: java, java-swing, java-ee, java-8

Tengo las clases Prestamo

```
public class Prestamo extends Pago{

      private Fecha[] fechasPago;


        public Prestamo(){}


        public void setFechasPago(Fecha[] fechasPago){
            this.fechasPago=fechasPago;
        }

        public Fecha[] getFechasPago(){
            return fechasPago;
        }

    }
```

y Fecha

```
public class Fecha {
    private int anio;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;

    public Fecha() {
    }

    public Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anio){
        setAnio(anio);
        setDia(dia);
        setMes(mes);
    }

    public int getAnio(){
        return anio;
    }

    public int getDia(){
        return dia;
    }


    public int getMes(){
        return mes;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio){
        this.anio=anio;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia){
        this.dia=dia;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes){
        this.mes=mes;
    }
}
```

Obviamente las clases tienen mas metodos y atributos solo es para el ejemplo.
por otro lado la pregunta seria, lo que pasa es que como ven ahi hay un atributo `private Fecha[] fechasPago;` el cual esta por lo siguiente, en el main se ingresa por teclado un dia, un mes y un año pero apartir de esa fecha se debe contar un mes despues durante un año, ejemplo si se ingresa dia 21, mes 06, año 2018 el vector debe guardar todos los 21 de cada mes hasta el año 2019 pero la pregunta seria como relaciono si en la clase `Prestamo` hay un vector de tipo `Fecha` ¿como se implementaria en el Main y que tambien se imprima cada mes hasta cumplir su fecha?

Comment: No se si soy malo leyendo o es la redacción pero no entendí tu pregunta.

Comment: Que no entendiste?

Comment: En el punto en que dices "¿Cómo relaciono si en la clase Prestamo hay un vector de tipo Fecha?" no se a que te refieras exactamente.¿Quieres decir que como compruebas un objeto Prestamo en concreto tenga una instancia no nula de Fecha[] asociada a su atributo fechasPago? Si ese es el caso simplemente has una condicional del estilo if (this.fechasPago == null) { /**/ } y dentro pon las acciones necesarias si se da tal condición. Si ese es el caso, sin embargo, no necesitarías hacer nada en el propio main sino en algún metodo de la clase Prestamo.

Comment: No, mira sabemos que `fechasPago` es de tipo `Fecha` y `Fecha` es una clase que maneja fechas, dia, mes. año, entonces tengo `Fecha[] fechasPago;` que es un vector y en tal vector se debe guardar las 12 fechas y despues imprimir esas fechas, la cuestion es que en main tengo que crear un objeto para interactuar con la clase `Prestamo` pero a su vez ese atributo es de tipo `Fecha` otra calse, como haria en ese caso.

Comment: `fechasPago` no es un vector, es un array. Calendar y Date son tu solucion.

Comment: @JDev Asi esta en los diagramas UML que me dieron y en los requisitos textuales y el tipo de fecha lo piden como dice la clase Fecha, no utilizamos Date

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobreescribir el metodo toString() en la clase fecha para que te muestre el formato que deseas:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return  dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio;
}
```

y en la clase prestamo crearias un metodo que rellenase el arreglo de fechas tomando como parametro la fecha inicial. luego para imprimir cada fecha solo bastaria con un for imprimiendo cada fecha:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fechasPago.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(fechasPago[i].toString());
    }
```